# Are they different flash players?

Tags: internet-explorer, flash

I am playing with Flash and C# using Shockwave. Today I started getting some strange "Configuration error" when running the Flash via my app. The strange thing is that running same Flash via IE causes the same error, but running it via Firefox or Chrome works fine.

Do IE, Firefox and Chrome use different Flash players?

One more thing, does Flash store some cache like a browser does? If so, how can I find this cache?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you can see [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) there are 3 different Flash Players. The one used for IE, the one used for FF(and other browsers like Chrome, Opera...) and there are a third one, that is bundled in Chrome (the pepper flash).

Comment: Thank you for your replay. So the Shockwave that is being used in c# is the one that's used in IE. Is there a way to use the other flash players via c#?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You can install different versions, and for each of them, you can install the normal or the debug version.